# Differentiating under the integral sign proof

Tags: real-analysis

Looking for some on understanding this proof that is my lecture notes. Can't really get to grips between why all these conditions are necessary.

**Theorem:**

If $f, \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ are continuous on $[a,b] \times [c,d]$,

then $\forall t \in (c,d)$ 
$F(t) = \int^b_a f(x,t) dx$ and $G(t) = \int^b_a \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) dx$ both exist on $(c,d)$ and $F$ is differentiable on $(c,d)$ with $F' = G$

**Proof**

Fix $t \in (c,d)$ 
On a closed interval, continuity implies uniform continuity so:
$\left|\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h} - G(t)\right| = \left|\int^b_a \frac{f(x,t+h) - f(x,t)}{h} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dx\right|$

Then $\exists\tau \in (t,t+h)$ by the  Mean Value Theorem such that the above is equal to $\left|\int^b_a \frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}(x, \tau) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t)\, dx\right|$

Now since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}$ is uniformly continuous so $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that $\forall h, |h| < \delta_{\epsilon}$, $\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}(x, \tau) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x, t)\right| < \epsilon$. Thus the integral is less than $\epsilon(b-a)$ and so $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \left|\frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h}\right| = G(t) \Rightarrow F'(t) = G(t)$

**My questions**

1) Why do $f, \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ need to be continuous? Is it to use the FTC?

2) Why do we need uniform continuity for this theorem to hold?

3) Why is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}$ uniformly continuous? Is it just because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is?

4) Why is it $|h| < \delta_{\epsilon} ?$ Isn't uniform continuity about $\forall x, y, |x-y | < \delta_{\epsilon} ect?$ Could someone write out the steps I am missing?

5) Why does the inequality directly after this hold? I presume it's a result of uniform continuity but this is in an unfamiliar context.

6) What is the intuition and applications of this theorem? Is it just the notion that instead of differentiating an integral we could instead just integrate the partial derivative?

Comment: Lebesgue or Riemann integral?

Comment: Hello we have been using Regulated Integrals, and I understand that Regulated implies Riemann so I guess the latter?

Comment: hmm... Riemann integral has less strong convergence theorems, so it would be difficult to weaken the assumptions. Using Lebesgue integral, the theorem is valid much weaker assumptions.

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking for weaker assumptions, more just asking why we need to  have these assumptions in the first place. I am more struggling with the proof itself.

Answer (score 3):

1) 2) You don't need that $f$ is continuous on the rectangle. You could slightly weaken this assumption. But is a simple to way to ensure that $F$ is well-defined (and continuous).

As for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, you need continuity to deduce that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\cdot, \tau_x) \to \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\cdot, t)$ uniformly as $\sup_x |\tau_x - t| \le h \to 0$. (Notice that $\tau$ depends on $x$!) This is needed for the convergence of the integral. With Lebesgue integral integral you can weaken that part gravely.

3) A continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous.

4) You use uniformly continuity to ensure $\delta_\epsilon$ is independent of $x$ and $\tau_x$. That is import for the uniform convergence.

5) Please revisit the definition of uniform continuity.

6) Yes (under given assumptions).